# Correct event managment architecture in web application

Tags: web-development, architectural-patterns, event-programming

My team and I are working on a large web application, and I've noticed that we're working in a way which I believe is an incorrect usage of flux (probably from lack of understanding).
We're using Angular 6 and angular-redux, but we use angular-redux more as an event manager than application state management i.e. dispatching changed data from a certain event from one component to other components, using the reducers as the observables which all other components subscribe to.
So basically, there isn't a real state.

So I've been wondering - if I'm correct and we're using it wrong, how should we manage this kind of events and data transfers? (I believe it might be angular services).
But if I'm wrong, then I'm asking why would anyone use this kind of event management, since it's terribly challenging for debugging and testing

Thanks a lot, waiting to hear your opinions!